# ¿Qué significa “el trasero se les movía...”?

Tags: significado

> El algodón de los campos ya había sido cosechado, y unas cuantas
>   mujeres con pañuelo en la cabeza estaban arrancando los tallos; el
>   trasero **se les movía** al sacudir el barro adherido a las raíces.

Según el diccionario, un significado de *mover* significa que “Menear o agitar una cosa o parte de algún cuerpo”.

Aquí, *se les movía*

1. es “moverse(reflexivo) a *algo*”?
2. o “mover algo (el trasero) a *algo*”  (objeto indirecto)?

Y del último “*algo*”, ¿se refiere a las demás mujeres, no la mujer que movía su trasero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"se" es reflexivo. "Les" es complemento indirecto.

En español, por algún motivo, no nos gusta demasiado utilizar determinantes posesivos. En su lugar, trasladamos la "posesión" al complemento indirecto.

> El trasero se **les** movía = **Sus** traseros se movían.

Así que "les" está indicando que es el trasero de ellas, se les movía a ellas. No es el trasero de otra persona.

---

Nota: en realidad, también es típico decir "Su trasero se les movía". En este caso, "les" es prescindible, actúa como dativo ético. Simplemente observa que, en español, es muy preferible utilizar pronombres (lo, la, le). Puedes añadir posesivos, pero el pronombre es preferible.

Comment: "les" es prescindible...... Significa que es lo mismo significado con  “el trasero se movía al sacudir...” ???

Comment: [Así que "les" está indicando que es el trasero de ellas, se les movía a ellas......... ] por qué necesitamos añadir “a ellas” (les)?

Comment: No, no, puse una línea horizontal para separar un anexo. La parte principal de la respuesta es la parte de arriba. "El trasero se les movía = sus traseros se movían". Les es necesario porque no hay un "su". La parte posesiva debe ir en algún sitio: o con "sus traseros" o en "el trasero se LES".

Comment: LEs sólo es prescindible si colocas "su". Entonces "les" sólo añade **énfasis** en que es "de ellas". Pero si no hay "su", entonces tiene que haber un "les" obligatoriamente.

Comment: @Fabiola “El trasero se les movía” es correcto. “El trasero se les movía a ellas” también es correcto, pero agregar “a ellas” sirve para enfatizar que se trata de “ellas, esas mujeres, las mujeres de las que estábamos hablando”. En este contexto no sería necesario agregar “a ellas” porque es obvio que se refiere a “las mujeres”.

Comment: Vale, he visto que has añadido una pregunta nueva. Es mejor publicar una pregunta separada, porque son temas distintos. Aun así, la respuesta es similar: nos gusta trasladar la carga posesiva a los pronombres. No necesariamente complemento indirecto, también puede ser directo (reflexivo). Solemos decir "Se peina el pelo" (a sí misma) en lugar de "peina su pelo", aunque también es correcta.