# Pronombre : Se “les” movía el trasero

Tags: pronombres

> El algodón de los campos ya había sido cosechado, y unas cuantas
>   mujeres con pañuelo en la cabeza estaban arrancando los tallos; el
>   trasero **se les movía** al sacudir el barro adherido a las raíces.

Mis dudas:

1. Si es necesario dice que “se **LES** movía” con **les** la cual indica una funcion de posesión **su**, por qué siempre decimos

*Se peina el pelo / se cepilla los dientes (sin objecto indirecto LE /LES) ???*

2. Si dice **...*el trasero se movía* (the butt moved) al sacudir el barro adherido a las raíces** , ¿está correcto y qué diferencias hay entre las dos?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [¿Qué significa “el trasero se les movía...”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/27271/qu%c3%a9-significa-el-trasero-se-les-mov%c3%ada)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, because this question was added to the other one, editing the original one to include this "second question", but it is a separate question actually. @Fabiola , you should delete the edit in the previous question. All the "new question" should be here.

Answer (score 3):

A la primera pregunta:

> Si es necesario dice que “se LES movía” con les la cual indica una funcion de >posesión su, por qué siempre decimos
>
> Se peina el pelo / se cepilla los dientes (sin objecto indirecto LE /LES) ???

Los ejemplos que das son de distinto tipo: en el caso de ***Se peina el pelo / se cepilla los dientes*** ya tienes un sujeto (que se supone implícito por el contexto de la acción: Pedro, Ana, el niño, él,...) y un objeto directo (el pelo, los dientes). La frase está completa y no se necesita más información o complementos para entender quién hace la acción sobre qué.

En cambio en el caso de ***...el trasero se movía***, si eliminas el complemento directo *les*, la frase estaría incompleta, y quien te escucha decir algo así te podría preguntar, *¿a quién se le movía el trasero?*, pues no queda claro en la frase.

A la segunda pregunta:

> Si dice ***...el trasero se movía (the butt moved) al sacudir el barro adherido a las raíces***, ¿está correcto y qué diferencias hay entre las dos?

Ocurre que la frase pierde información, pues se desconoce a quién se le movía. No sería incorrecto como tal, pero la oración estaría incompleta.

Comment: Gracias. ¿Qué tal si dice “el trasero se movía a ellas”? ¿Está correcto con el mismo significado?

Comment: Aún necesitarías *les*: *el trasero se les movía a ellas*. El que añadas el pronombre *a ellas* o no, depende de que se sepa de quien estás hablando. Es decir, puedes eliminarlo si existe un antecedente en la frase anterior (unas cuantas mujeres), en el caso de que no lo hubiera o no se sepa de quién se habla tienes que usarlo.

Answer (score 1):

[...] y **unas cuantas mujeres** con pañuelo en la cabeza estaban arrancando los tallos; el trasero se **les** movía al sacudir el barro adherido a las raíces.

- **movérsele **a alguien** el trasero** sería la forma infinitiva de este verbo pronominal (intransitivo). El pronombre les se sustituye a las mujeres.
- el trasero **se les movía** al sacudir el barro adherido a las raíces.

"les" se refiere a las mujeres.

**their** butts [or derrières or rear ends] moved** when they shook the mud off the roots.

moverse es un verbo pronominal seguido de un complemento de objeto indirecto. Por ejemplo: Se **le** mueve [a él la cabeza]. Y no es el uso transitivo: la cabeza mueve las ideas.

Otro punto: la palabra trasero es singular pero al traducirla se pone en el plural: their butts moved.

El trasero de las mujeres, pues, se refiere al trasero de cada una de ellas. No se puede hacer esto en inglés.

La cara de los niños, en el singular, se dice: the children's faces. Es por considerarse que cada niño tiene una cara. Los dos idiomas no tienen la misma lógica.

Comment: Gracias!! Entiendo más. :)